# Translating python code from unix to windows - Multiprocessing Calls

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Can someone help me I'm trying to translate the code from the link below to work in windows.

http://wilson.bronger.org/lens_calibration_tutorial/calibrate.py

```
import subprocess, os, os.path, sys, multiprocessing, math, re, contextlib, glob, codecs, struct, numpy

from scipy.optimize.minpack import leastsq

candidate_groups = [['distortion\\Standard--13.3--5.5.DNG'],['distortion\\Standard--17.5--5.7.DNG']]

def call_exiv2(candidate_group):
    exiv2_process = subprocess.Popen(
        ["exiv2", "-PEkt", "-g", "Exif.Photo.LensModel", "-g", "Exif.Photo.FocalLength", "-g", "Exif.Photo.FNumber"]
        + candidate_group, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    lines = exiv2_process.communicate()[0].splitlines()
    assert exiv2_process.returncode in [0, 253]
    result = {}
    for line in lines:
        filename, data = line.split("Exif.Photo.")
        filename = filename.rstrip()
        if not filename:
            assert len(candidate_group) == 1
            filename = candidate_group[0]
        fieldname, field_value = data.split(None, 1)
        exif_data = result.setdefault(filename, [None, float("nan"), float("nan")])
        if fieldname == "LensModel":
            exif_data[0] = field_value
        elif fieldname == "FocalLength":
            exif_data[1] = float(field_value.partition("mm")[0])
        elif fieldname == "FNumber":
            exif_data[2] = float(field_value.partition("F")[2])
    for filename, exif_data in list(result.copy().items()):
        result[filename] = tuple(exif_data)
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for group_exif_data in pool.map(call_exiv2, candidate_groups):
        file_exif_data.update(group_exif_data)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

However, there seems to be issues with the multiprocessing sections. I initially used 2to3 to convert the code to python3 as I'm using 3.4. I also added the code below above the `pool = multiprocessing.Pool()` calls.

```
if __name___ == '__main__': 
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
```

Which got rid of one error but I still have the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "calibrate.py", line 166, in <module>
        for group_exif_data in pool.map(call_exiv2, candidate_groups):
    File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 260, in map
        return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 599, in get
        raise self._value
    TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

I initially thought it might have to do with Pickling, but couldn't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: From messing around with the cut down code. It seems to be when the program hits the line `filename, data = line.split("Exif.Photo.")`

Comment: OK seems that adding/changing the lines to `temp = line.decode("utf-8")` next line `filename, data = temp.split("Exif.Photo.")... seems to fix the problem... anyway how was I meant to decode the original error message? Is there a way to get better error messages?

Comment: That seems like a very good question, but a different one. You could prepare a small example demonstrating this problem, and ask another question. Or, if you think this question is of no use to anyone, and because no one has answered, you can rewrite it completely (please note that in general this is discouraged, but in this situation it would be OK I think). Btw. you don't need to add "edit" statements in the question - they are irrelevant, and if someone's really interested what was an "edit", the post's history is easily available.

Comment: Probably you want `str` (text) instead of `bytes` in Python 3. Passing `universal_newlines=True` to `subprocess.Popen` does that for you, but it uses the default ANSI codepage instead of UTF-8. Otherwise you can decode all at once before splitting: `lines = exiv2_process.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8').splitlines()`

Comment: For initial testing you could use `import multiprocessing.dummy as multiprocessing`. This will test with multithreading instead of spawning processes. The error messages within process should be more informative.

Comment: Strange; using Python 3.4 you should see something like `multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: """ <real traceback here> """ The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: <crappy traceback you pasted above here>`